# JSON object displays null

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, poco

This is my model.

```
    public class User
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Headline { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Phonenumber> Phonenumbers { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Email> Emails { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Position> Positions { get; set; }
}
```

This is the GET method.

```
    // GET api/App
    public IEnumerable<User> GetUsers()
    {
        db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        return db.Users.AsEnumerable();
    }
```

I have disabled proxy creation because apparently there's some sort of issue with Entity Framework and seriliazation.

When I goto localhost:12345/api/App/ it returns the following JSON object. As you'll notice the Addresses field and all the way to Positions is displayed as null.

```
[{"$id":"1","Id":"1","Username":"Bob","FirstName":"Foo","LastName":"Bar","Password":"123","Headline":"Something","Addresses":null,"Phonenumbers":null,"Emails":null,"Positions":null}]
```

However I do not understand why it's null, because it used to display them. I can confirm it's there, the data, when I goto localhost:12345/api/App/1 where it displays:

```
{"$id":"1","Addresses":[{"$id":"2","Id":"3","Uaddress":"Test address","Country":"Fantasy Land","Zipcode":"0000","Cycle":0,"UserId":"3","User":{"$ref":"1"}}],"Phonenumbers":[{"$id":"3","Id":"2","Number":"12345678","Cycle":0,"UserId":"3","User":{"$ref":"1"}}],"Emails":[{"$id":"4","Id":"2","Uemail":"bob@example.com","Cycle":0,"UserId":"3","User":{"$ref":"1"}}],"Positions":[{"$id":"5","Company":{"$id":"6","Id":"2","Name":"Bobs ApS","Type":"Bobs","Industry":"Magic","Size":"1337"},"Id":"2","Title":"CEO","Iscurrent":true,"CompanyId":"2","UserId":"1","User":{"$ref":"1"}}],"Id":"1","Username":"bob","FirstName":"Foo","LastName":"Bar","Password":"1234","Headline":"Something"}
```

As you'll see the field are all filled out with data. Any ideas why it's not displaying when I try to get all users?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now you have disabled the Proxy, Lazy Loading is not fetching the child entities for you. You will need to ask for them specifically:

```
return db.Users.Include(x => x.Addresses).Include(x => x.Positions).AsEnumerable();
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I appreciate your quick answer. Would you however also know why there is this seriliazation bug with EF which causes me to disable the proxy?

Comment: I think (?) it's because Navigable entities can reference each other so it's an infinite serialization? User goes to Addresses but Addresses goes to Users who have Addresses who have Users -  that can't be serialized. I might be wrong here though...

Comment: Okay sounds reansonable. Thank you once again for your fast replies. Have a good day :)

Comment: @twice Look into data contracts and you should be able to re-enable proxy creation. Read this article that explains how to serialize circular references. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh241056(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: @spy890 I'm planning to use the JSON.NET framework, wouldn't it interfere with it?